# Reading HDF5 file initially fast then becomes very slow

Tags: python, performance, hdf5, h5py

I have a few hdf5 files and want to read them in python using a generator (using h5py). However, the problem is that when I try to read from HDF5 files, first it is very fast (0.08 seconds when I call `data_generator` every time), and after I called `data_generator` about 10 times, it will become like 5 seconds (100x slower) each time I call `data_generator`. However the 10 times are not fixed - sometimes it could be 11 times and sometimes it could be 9.

The code is like this:

```
def data_generator(start, end):
  batch_size = 32 # hard coee for demo purpose
  size = 1000 # hard code for demo purpose
  for i in range(start, end):
      for j in range(int(size/batch_size)): # for all examples
          print("i is", i, "j is", j)
          if ((j+1)*batch_size <= size):
              f1 = h5py.File(os.path.join(processed_data_folder, "features_" + str(i) + ".hdf5"), 'r')
              X = f1["features"][j*batch_size:(j+1)*batch_size]
              f2 = h5py.File(os.path.join(processed_data_folder, "labels_" + str(i) + ".hdf5"), 'r')
              y = f2["labels"][j*batch_size:(j+1)*batch_size]                
              yield X, y
```

When I created my HDF5 files, I use the code like below:

```
def parse_data_frame_hdf5_without_scaling(df, fold_num):
  labels = []
  labels_file = os.path.join(processed_data_folder, "labels_" + str(fold_num) + '.hdf5')
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
      try:
          im = imread(os.path.join(data_folder, row['Image Index']))
      except IOError:
          print("can't find file or read data" + row['Image Index'])
      else:
          im = resize(im, output_shape = (resized_height, resized_width), mode = 'constant', preserve_range = True)

          im = im.T.flatten()[:, np.newaxis].T
          # print("shape of im is", im.shape, "type is", type(im))
          create_or_append_hdf5(im, fold_num)
          labels.append(row['isPneumonia'])

  with h5py.File(labels_file, 'w') as hf:
      hf.create_dataset("labels",  data=labels)
  print("labels shape is",len(labels), "fold ", fold_num)
```

Where the create_or_append_hdf5 is like this:

```
def create_or_append_hdf5(img, fold_num):
  img = np.asarray(img).reshape(len(img),resized_height,resized_width,1)
  feature_file = os.path.join(processed_data_folder, "features_" + str(fold_num) + '.hdf5')
  if(os.path.exists(feature_file)):
      with h5py.File(feature_file, 'a') as hf:
          hf["features"].resize((hf["features"].shape[0] + img.shape[0]), axis = 0)
          hf["features"][-img.shape[0]:] = img
  else:        
      with h5py.File(feature_file, 'w') as hf:
          hf.create_dataset("features",  data = img, maxshape=(None, resized_height, resized_width, 1))
```

Originally I thought it is like disk throttling issue (since I am using a VM on Azure), but then I investigated the IOPS and the disk read throughput, all of them are within 30% of the Azure VM allowed values; then I suspect there might be some performance issues when creating my HDF5 file, however if this is the case, then it won't read fast in the first a few instances.

I was also thinking maybe the data varies a lot in the HDF5 file so the disk reading time will vary a lot, however I examined the data and didn't find any special data. BTW, all the data is a float 32 (32, 512, 512, 1) numpy array (it's for image processing).

I am really struggling with this since it lower the performance a lot - but I cannot figure out why. Any pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: Do the file and datasets exist? It looks like you keep increasing the size of the dataset, so it's possible that HDF5 needs to restructure the file to deal with that.

Comment: If you don't set a chunksize, h5py will do that for you. If you know exactly how you read or write your files this will be usually not an optimal chunksize for your needs. 1) The chunk-cache will be deleted if you open and close the file with every access avoid this. 2) Set a proper chunksize on your own (possibly (1,resized_height, resized_width, 1), but according to the way you wan't to read it afterwards. 3) Avoid fancy indexing (all indices should be specified)